# What is the oracle in every quantum algorithm?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I hope this question won't be closed.

There is a machine called oracle which appears in a lot of algorithms of quantum computing, such as Deutsch's algorithm and QFT period-finding.

This oracle machine really makes me confused.

I've read something about computing theory, and in that, it mentions the oracle as a machine which has a super magic power that can solve a specific question.

But here comes the tricky part: if these quantum algorithms depend on such a super magic power machine, doesn't that mean that all these algorithms are no use in real life since we don't have the magic to make that oracle?

The appearance of the $U_f$ gate in these algorithms really makes me confused.

Another point is that, why can't I say that "I can create a machine which can solve any NP questions in polynomic time"

The method is to suppose there is an oracle which can solve that question in polynomic time, and use that oracle to solve it.

We even don't need a quantum machine at all. If those algorithms are seen as useful, why isn't my method?

I don't want to explain more. If you still can't understand my question, I'll just ask one question.

The question is "how could you implement the oracle?"

**[Cross-posted on quantumcomputing.stackexchange](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/37508/what-is-the-oracle-in-every-quantum-algorithm)**

Comment: Do you understand the classical problem?

Comment: The oracle is usually used to make constructions and proofs. It is not assumed to exist in real life. It would help if you can give a specific example of a discussion including an oracle which is confusing to you.

Comment: It is not clear why the classical oracle is fine for you, but the quantum one not. If the former is not clear, I suggest to migrate this question to theoretical computer science or so.

Comment: @Tobias Fünke :the reason that the classical oralce is fine for me  is that in that they are just used for mathmatics but here we are creating quantum computer.

Comment: @DanDan0101 the algorithm which I mentioned all use the oracle.

Comment: If [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsch%E2%80%93Jozsa_algorithm#Problem_statement) does not answer the question migrate it to [Quantum Computing SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/20670/).

Comment: What do you mean with "creating quantum computer"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Tobias Fünke   I think my question is very easy to understand, the algorithm used an oralce which is a fictitious machine, it can't be implmented in the real world. "creating quantum computer" just mean quantum computer is in real-world, it is not just a fictitious  machine, we need to create it to use. we are not use it to write a fiction or do some math provement.

Comment: @Community   what can I clarify, the question is very simple and easy to understand, oracle is a fictitious machine, those algorithms used a fictitious which can't be impelmented in the real-world.  You can use oracle to do math provement or write fiction, but if you use it to implement a quantum computer, that just like say"give a magic wand, with this magic wand, I designed an algorithm which can solve NP question,", it is ridiculous, so the question is what is the magic wand.

Comment: @Kurt G.   definitly it dosn't. since it use the oracle, but it didn't say what is the oracle.

Comment: I don't want to explain more, if you still don't understand my question, I would ask just one question, how to implement the orcale?

Comment: @tangyao There's nothing special about [oracles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/concepts-oracles),- neither classical nor quantum ones. Oracle is just unnamed code block, aka. function which behaves as classical or quantum algorithm needs to,- without going into details of that function implementation. It's just a way to simplify algorithm specification. Of course, finally- all oracles must be implemented also, [here you can look](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/2386/1/012010/pdf) for implementations of some oracles.

Comment: looking up in this article about quantum algorithms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_algorithm it seems to me that the question is valid for this site , so I vote to reopen

Comment: Please mark crossposts.

Comment: Voting to reopen. A perfectly clear question with a good answer below.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing magical about [oracles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/concepts-oracles),- neither classical nor quantum ones. Oracle is just an algorithm **subroutine** which behaves as classical or quantum algorithm needs to,- without going into details of that function/procedure implementation. That's why it's called a back box. It's just a way to simplify algorithm specification.

Let's take a *classical* algorithm example, recursive quicksort :

```
algorithm quicksort(A, lo, hi) is 
  // Ensure indices are in correct order
  if lo >= hi || lo < 0 then 
    return    
  // Partition array and get the pivot index
  p := partition(A, lo, hi) 
  quicksort(A, lo, p - 1) // Left side of pivot
  quicksort(A, p + 1, hi) // Right side of pivot
```

In definition of this sorting algorithm I need to split array into 2 parts and return pivot point, which is done by specific subroutine "partition()". Quantum computing is very young field (compared to a classical computing). It doesn't have thousands of quantum algorithms invented, nor huge number of specific subroutines, because for exponential expansion of quantum algorithms (and quantum programming languages, not to say HIGH-level of abstraction QC languages which is too faint fantasy now at this point) we need a few millions logical qubits. Which is only on a research roadmap.
So, a couple of used subroutines fits under "oracle" definition well, until QC field is only at the hardware and/or "quantum assembly" programming level.

Sure, finally- most oracles can be implemented in hardware also, [here you can look](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/2386/1/012010/pdf) for implementations of some oracles. Some oracles may be classical ones. This may suggest that quantum computer may work best in tandem with a classical computer. Because not all algorithms are parallel, some may be strictly sequential and/or in the need of a classical computing determinism. So, I imagine that most practical device would be with both kinds of processors integrated CPU + QPU.

Comment: Well, not all oracles can necessarily be implemented. E.g.,to prove equality of separation of complexity classes relative to an oracle, random oracles are a popular tool. (And those results don't tell you much about the relation of the classes, except that certain proof techniques don't apply.)

Comment: I've changed in the post to "most oracles" to account for your note. Albeit [automated theorem provers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_theorem_proving) nowadays is also an option in software, at least in a classical one. I believe random oracle(s) can be modelled by reading natural noise sources,- i.e. [atmospheric noise](https://www.random.org/), photons from cosmic microwave background, etc. So this is also implementable as some form of a physical device generating/reading random outputs. We can even try to build [Quantum_noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_noise) generator